# Gmail feed retrieve email text

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail, atom-feed, feed, feedparser

Is it possible to retrieve complete email messages/ not just summary from the gmail feed?
Is there a way to change the feed?

I tried parsing a feed and only got this:

```xml
<feed xmlns="http://purl.org/atom/ns#" version="0.3">
<title>Gmail - Inbox for vladotrocol@gmail.com</title>
<tagline>New messages in your Gmail Inbox</tagline>
<fullcount>126</fullcount>
<link rel="alternate" href="http://mail.google.com/mail/u/0" type="text/html"/>
<modified>2014-01-04T01:26:09Z</modified>
<entry>
<title>Cyrille</title>
<summary>SUP!</summary>
<link rel="alternate" href="http://mail.google.com/mail/u/0?account_id=xxx@gmail.com&message_id=xxx&view=conv&extsrc=atom" type="text/html"/>
<modified>2014-01-04T00:05:09Z</modified>
<issued>2014-01-04T00:05:09Z</issued>
<id>tag:gmail.google.com,2004:xxx</id>
<author>
<name>Vlad Otrocol</name>
<email>xxx@gmail.com</email>
</author>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a gmail filter to forward mail based on a rule to the inbound app engine mail receiver?

Comment: OK.. should have mentioned I wanted to do this programatically.. no clicks involved. How can I make google app engine forward all my gmail emails?

Comment: I actually looked at this before. How can I make google app engine run a custom app script? I got this tutorial to communicate between app script and GAE https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/appengine. But how do i trigger this script programatically?

Comment: You can't.  You can make the script run on a timer though.

Comment: I want the user to use the google id to connect to the google app and see all his messages. I guess this is not possible. I tried a lot of things. IMAP does not work, Atom feed only has summaries for only unread messages, Context.io is not free. I guess it is not possible in the end

Comment: Script runs on timer, polls for oauth tokens from appengine, retrieves mail and puts in location accessible by app.